# KMeditation- Abdominal distention

Tags: vipassana, buddhist, mahasi

I have been trying to pratice vipassana with abdominal movements-
Q

1. I never feel the movements getting settled or a state of no movements
2. about 5 min after starting the meditation I feel tightness in the upper part of rhe nose, forehead and the vertex of my head which lead me to stop the meditation.

What can i do for this?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are trying too hard, exerting too much mental effort, which is causing the tightness in the head.

Possibly you can try to just sit still, with your eyes open. Place one or both hands on your abdomen; to allow the movements of the abdomen to come to your mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying too hard. You must relax and observe. If the mind is tense, is atta, it's a personal sense of self trying to reach something (or kill something). That's not vipassana, just self delusion. Meditation is supposed to be fun, as Bhante Vimalaramsi used to say. Most of bhikkhus and meditation teachers in Theravada tradition, recommend an open, relaxed attention. And relaxing exercises too! If you can't relax your body at will during meditation, you can try yoga asanas, doing exercises before meditation or psychological techniques such as progressive muscle relaxation, autogenic training, etc. I hope this was helpful. Metta, bro.